# Seeing nested folders from a dlna server?

Tags: media-player

I am running Gerbera as a dnla media server on my Linux box. I have 100s of files, both music and video organized in nested folders.

I recently acquired an Android box, X88 Max+

I connect through my home network and can select music or video. I see the entire libraries but there is no structure. Just everything presented in alphabetical order.

I do see music albums, and then I can select and see the individual tracks. But I do not have a higher folder grouping all my, for example, Beatles albums together.

When I connect my blu-ray player to the dlna server, I do see the structure.

Is there a way to see the structure on the android box?

I checked with an app called BubblePnP on my android tablet, and it retains the structure.

I will try to install on my android box.

And help is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to register my Google account in this box. It was difficult with the very limited remote.

I installed BubblePnp from Playstore. I could not get it to play my media because the remote is so limited in function.

I have ordered a keyboard/mouse USB wireless to use. That should solve the issue.

But to my surprise, and delight, the standard media player now shows one level of folders. Not a complete solution but a big improvement.